CMake change launch directory
I switched my project from Visual Studio to CMake + VS Code. I am fairly a beginner to CMake.
The project consists of 4 subdirectories: 1) script, 2) grid 3) app and 4) 64Bit. The first 3 directories each have CMakeLists.txt files. There is also a top-level CMakeLists.txt file.
The 64Bit directory is for distribution and contains other DLLs and many other files so that the executable can run.
I can generate DLLs and the EXE in the project/build directory and then copy them to project/64Bit directory using a command similar to the following:
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy 
    $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}> ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/64Bit/${PROJECT_NAME}.exe)

My problem is, when I use "Launch the selected target in the terminal window" button in VS Code, then it attempts to launch project/build/app/Release/app.exe whereas I want it to launch project/64Bit/app.exe file.
Is there a way I can change the launch target either from CMakeLists.txt files or using the GUI of the CMake extension? I am also thinking that this issue will cause me Debugging problems later on.
Thanks in advance!

"The 64Bit directory is for distribution" - In CMake preparing files for distribution is known as installation. As for building process, it is discouraged during this process to create/delete files outside of a build tree.

I use the same approach with VS and it works seamlessly. Not sure why it should not be doable with CMake. is there a better approach for this in CMake?

Set the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY target property.

That did not work but a similar one worked: SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/64Bit). Now works exactly as I want, many thanks!

maybe related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1937

You can define what program you'd like to launch by adding or editing the following line in your launch.json file (you might want to edit the exact location a bit):
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/.../app.exe"
Here is an example of an updated launch.json file, but I will advise you to edit what you have rather than making a new configuration:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "myRunner",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/64Bit/app.exe",    //added/edited line
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    //...
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}


This will impact your entire Debug Configuration, so consider creating a backup first if you plan to work on other projects in the future. Also make sure to run the file using the correct Debug Configuration, in the above example that would be myRunner.
Hope this helps!

I have not tried but this might work but it is very convenient to configure CMake and then do things via it.
